# Error with embedding javascript form (Active Campaign) on .NET

Tags: javascript, .net, activecampaign

I'm trying to embed a 'simple embed' javascript form from Active Campaign on a .NET environment (custom CMS I think).
I got several problems:

- The form styling isn't working
- When submitting the form, the page refresh, but the submit doesn't work.

I got no Javascript errors in Inspector. When I try to embed this on a Apache environment the form works correctly. That's the workaround I currently made, but it's not scalable and it's not workable on mobile.

I'm not a .NET developer, the website built by another company, but they can't figure out what the problem is. The URL of the environment is: http://hallidays.cmspreview.co.uk/converting-landingpage

The code of the form is:

```
<div class="_form_8"></div><script src="https://hallidays.activehosted.com/f/embed.php?id=8" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Comment: I saw that the whole page is between <form> and </form>. Maybe that's why it doesn't submit the form?

Comment: *When submitting the form, the page refresh, but the submit doesn't work.*. That is incorrect. The form is posting to `http://hallidays.cmspreview.co.uk/converting-landingpage` as defined in the `form`s `action` attribute and the values are correctly passed as formdata.

Comment: *The form styling isn't working* How shall we know how the form is actually supposed to be styled? Also you set the `color` of the parent `div` to white and the `color` of the descendant `input` to `inherit`, which kinda makes the text invisible/white as well.

Comment: See for example the form on http://hallidays.cmspreview.co.uk/form-templates/form-8.html, as it should be this way. So, yes, I agree, the form does submit to the /converting-landingpage, but it's not the URL it should submit to.. 
Same with styling

Comment: Why arent you just changing the action to the URL it should go to? Also open the console and check the errors you are getting while loading your site.

Comment: @Lain I'm not the developer of this site, I'm the marketing manager of the agency that has this site as a client. I don't know anything form .NET, only PHP :-). I don't know either why there is a <form> in the top of the page, and don't know if we can change it..

Comment: Talk to your developer... `form` is there because you have a `form` you want to submit. Tell your developer to remove the `runat="server"` from the `form` tag.